# DraftJS blockstyle (header-one) not getting triggered

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have used draftJS in my project as a note taker. The inline styles are working perfectly fine but the blockType aren't.

Used the RichUtils to toggleInlineStyles and toggleBlockType.

Main DraftJS.jsx file :

```
class PageContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
      alignment: "align-left",
    };
    this.setDomEditorRef = ref => (this.domEditor = ref);
    this.focus = () => this.domEditor.focus();
    this.onChange = editorState => {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        editorState,
      });
    };
  }

  handleKeyCommand = command => {
    const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(
      this.state.editorState,
      command,
    );
    if (newState) {
      this.onChange(newState);
      return "handled";
    }
    return "not-handled";
  };

  blockStyleFn = () => {
    return this.state.alignment;
  };

  handleAlignment = alignment => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      alignment,
    });
  };

  toggleInlineStyle = inlineStyle => {
    this.onChange(
      RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, inlineStyle),
    );
  };

  toggleBlockType = blockType => {
    this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleBlockType(this.state.editorState, blockType));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen ">
        <div className="overflow-hidden shadow-md min-w-[422px] rounded-2xl ">
          <div
            onClick={this.focus}
            className="editors min-h-[210px] break-words text-base  p-6 bg-white border-b-[1px] border-primary-400">
            <Editor
              blockStyleFn={this.blockStyleFn}
              className="text-secondary-400"
              editorState={this.state.editorState}
              handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              placeholder="Take notes here..."
              spellCheck={true}
              ref={this.setDomEditorRef}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="flex justify-between py-4 px-6 ">
            <div className="flex flex-1 justify-between">
              <InlineStyleControls
                editorState={this.state.editorState}
                onToggleInLineStyle={this.toggleInlineStyle}
                onToggleBlock={this.toggleBlockType}
                focus={this.focus}
              />
            </div>

            <VerticalBorder className="mx-7" />

            <AlignTextControls
              handleAlignment={this.handleAlignment}
              focus={this.focus}
              currentAlignment={this.state.alignment}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

InLineStyleControls.jsx :

```
const InlineStyleControls = props => {
  const INLINE_STYLES = [
    {
      label: "Bold",
      style: "BOLD",
      icon: bold => <BoldIcon bold={bold} />,
    },
    {
      label: "Italic",
      style: "ITALIC",
      icon: bold => <ItalicIcon bold={bold} />,
    },
    {
      label: "Underline",
      style: "UNDERLINE",
      icon: bold => <UnderlineIcon bold={bold} />,
    },
    {
      label: "H1",
      style: "header-one",
      icon: bold => <TextIcon bold={bold} />,
    },
  ];

  let currentStyle = props.editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle();

  const selection = props.editorState.getSelection();

  const blockType = props.editorState
    .getCurrentContent()
    .getBlockForKey(selection.getStartKey())
    .getType();

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-1 justify-between">
      {INLINE_STYLES.map(type => (
        <StyleButton
          key={type.label}
          active={
            type.label === "H1"
              ? type.style === blockType
              : currentStyle.has(type.style)
          }
          icon={type.icon}
          onToggle={type.label === "H1" ? props.onToggleBlock : props.onToggleInLineStyle}
          style={type.style}
          focus={props.focus}
        />
      ))}
      <span className="cursor-pointer">
        <TextColor />
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

StyleButton.jsx:

```
class StyleButton extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onToggle = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.onToggle(this.props.style);
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <span className={` cursor-pointer ${this.props.class} `} onMouseDown={this.onToggle} onMouseUp={this.props.focus} >
        {this.props.icon(this.props.active ? 2 : 1)}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Problem : Everything is working fine except the "header-one" and I not able to figure out why.

I used the rich editor [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/0m86mwzp2p?file=/src/examples/Rich.js)  to build this.

Edit : I found the problem. The problem was due to tailwind css. When I remove tailwind from my project everything is working fine. any idea on to how to make draftJS work with tailwind?

Comment: but header-one is inline style not block style

Comment: tried the inline style too. didn't work. In the example link that I have used, the header-one is executed using toggleBlockType function.

Comment: @AshwinBabu just want to say thank you for your example code, it helped me fix some of the issues i encountered with draftjs, cheers

Comment: @ezennnn glad I was of help :)